# Detect url / links and replace image with img tag and links with a href

Tags: javascript, html, regex, image

I am trying to write a function that would take a string, parse it, and replace the image urls with a `<img src="image">` and the links with `<a href="link">link</a>`.

this is what i did :

```
var __urlRegex = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
var __imgRegex = /^ftp|http|https?:\/\/(?:[a-z\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}(?:\/[^\/#?]+)+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$/ig;

function parseURL($string){
    var exp = __urlRegex;
    return $string.replace(exp,function(match){
            if(__imgRegex.test(match,contents)){
                return '<img src="'+contents+'" width="200" />';
            }
            else{
                return '<a href="'+contents+'" target="_blank">'+contents+'</a>';
            }
        }
    );
}
```

The regexes work fine when i did some tests. However on implementation there's some wierd mumbo jumbo happening. If i throw say 5 image urls at it, it parses the 1st as an image but the second as a link and this goes on alternatively!!

Where I am going wrong?

Sample string i used for testing :

```
This is a kitten http://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/filepicker%2FvCleswcKTpuRXKptjOPo_kitten.jpg
with a sibling which is also a kitten http://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/filepicker%2FvCleswcKTpuRXKptjOPo_kitten.jpg
and a sister which is also a kitten http://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/filepicker%2FvCleswcKTpuRXKptjOPo_kitten.jpg
and lots of kittens
http://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/filepicker%2FvCleswcKTpuRXKptjOPo_kitten.jpg
http://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/filepicker%2FvCleswcKTpuRXKptjOPo_kitten.jpg
http://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/filepicker%2FvCleswcKTpuRXKptjOPo_kitten.jpg
http://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/filepicker%2FvCleswcKTpuRXKptjOPo_kitten.jpg
```

And this is the output that i get

```
<p>This is a kitten <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/filepicker%2FvCleswcKTpuRXKptjOPo_kitten.jpg" width="200">
with a sibling which is also a kitten <a href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/filepicker%2FvCleswcKTpuRXKptjOPo_kitten.jpg" target="_blank">http://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/filepicker%2FvCleswcKTpuRXKptjOPo_kitten.jpg</a>
and a sister which is also a kitten <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/filepicker%2FvCleswcKTpuRXKptjOPo_kitten.jpg" width="200">
and lots of kittens
undefined
<img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/filepicker%2FvCleswcKTpuRXKptjOPo_kitten.jpg" width="200">
<a href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/filepicker%2FvCleswcKTpuRXKptjOPo_kitten.jpg" target="_blank">http://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/filepicker%2FvCleswcKTpuRXKptjOPo_kitten.jpg</a>
<img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/filepicker%2FvCleswcKTpuRXKptjOPo_kitten.jpg" width="200"></p>
```

Comment: You should include the sample links you are passing to this function.

Comment: You need to use `contents` as a variable: `' ... href="'+ contents +'" ... '`

Comment: Updated the post with a sample that i used for testing.

Comment: Thats a bad typo on my part. Sorry! fixed it. Even then the stuff creates a weird output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [RegExp.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

> test called multiple times on the same global regular expression
>   instance will advance past the previous match.

[RegExp.lastIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex)

> A read/write integer property that specifies the index at which to start the next match.

As the documentations specify, [lastIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) will store the position which [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) will start matching.

So basically when you have an instance of RegExp, each call to [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) advances the [lastIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex). Once it found the first occurrence, it will look beyond that and try to find another match. Well, there are none anymore, so it returns **false**. The [lastIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) gets re set to `0`, and next call to [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) will start from the beginning and it will return **true** and so on...

So you will need to reset the [lastIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) property to `0` in order to [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) always start matching in the beginning of the next string.

```
__imgRegex.lastIndex=0;
```

---

[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Victornpb/VSRFX/4/)

```
function parseURL($string){

    var exp = __urlRegex;
    return $string.replace(exp,function(match){
            __imgRegex.lastIndex=0;
            if(__imgRegex.test(match)){
                return '<img src="'+match+'" class="thumb" />';
            }
            else{
                return '<a href="'+match+'" target="_blank">'+match+'</a>';
            }
        }
    );
}
```

EDIT:

Your regex was incorrectly matching `http://google.com` as a image. Also test expect just one argument.

```
__imgRegex.test('http://google.com') //true
```

Since you first check is a text is a link, there's no need to check if it is a link again, you can just check if it has a image extension.

```
var __imgRegex = /\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$/i;
```

Comment: +1 for the last part. Thanks.
However, even if i don't reset the lastIndex, i get the same correct desired result! How would that be explained?